# Есть ли библиотека для работы с RDP на уровне TCP? Без окон

Tags: c#, rdp

Ищу библиотеку, которая позволила бы общаться с удаленным компьютером по протоколу RDP, но без окон. Мне не нужно управление. По сути мне надо лишь проверять доступность множества серверов по RDP.

Пока видел:
 1. ActiveX компонент с wrapper'ом. Но он требует окно, что логично. Но мне не подходит. 
 2. Смотрел спецификацию протокола. Там все не просто. Много структур. Для всего, вроде есть описание и возможно придется обходиться этим.

Есть мысли?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Идём в менеджер Nuget-пакетов и ищем что-нибудь по слову `RDP`
2. Находим там `FreeRDP-Sharp`.
3. Устанавливаем, смотрим что в нём есть через `Class View`. Замечаем пространство имён `Core`, в нём класс `RDP`, делаем предположение что это то, что нам нужно.
4. Для проверки пишем простой код:

   ```
       var rdp = new FreeRDP.Core.RDP();
       rdp.Connect("192.168.0.10", "", "user", "password");
       Console.WriteLine(rdp.Connected);
       Console.ReadKey();
   ```

Всё, проверка пройдена - мы присоединились к серверу по RDP и получили статус соединения.

Если нужны детали реализации - идём на гитхаб и смотрим исходники проекта. По сути, это просто обёртка над unsafe-библиотекой FreeRDP, в которой можно (при наличии должных знаний C++) посмотреть детали реализации.

Comment: Натыкался на FreeRDP, но не видел обертки для sharp. Огромное спасибо!